# How to test "errorComponent" in "defineAsyncComponent" in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I was learning about [**Async Components**](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html) in Vue. Unfortunately in that documentation Vue did not show any example of using **Async Components** in the `<template>` part of a Vue SFC. So after searching on the web and reading some articles like [this one](https://learnvue.co/2021/06/lazy-load-components-in-vue-with-defineasynccomponent/#lazy-loading-a-popup-component-with-defineasynccomponent) and also [this one](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/async-components-in-vue-3), I tried to use this code to my Vue component:

```html
<!-- AsyncCompo.vue -->
<template>
    <h1>this is async component</h1>
    <button @click="show = true">login show</button>
    <div v-if="show">
        <LoginPopup></LoginPopup>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent, ref } from 'vue';
import ErrorCompo from "@/components/ErrorCompo.vue";

const LoginPopup = defineAsyncComponent({
     loader: () => import('@/components/LoginPopup.vue'),
     /* -------------------------- */
     /* the part for error handling */
     /* -------------------------- */
     errorComponent: ErrorCompo,
     timeout: 10
     }
)
export default {
   
    components: {
        LoginPopup,
    },
     
    setup() {
        const show = ref(false);
        
        return {
            show,
        }
    }, // end of setup
}
</script>
```

And here is the code of my Error component:

```html
<!-- ErrorCompo.vue -->
<template>
    <h5>error component</h5>
</template>
```

Also here is the code of my Route that uses this component:

```html
<!-- test.vue -->
<template>
    <h1>this is test view</h1>
    <AsyncCompo></AsyncCompo>
</template>

<script>

import AsyncCompo from '../components/AsyncCompo.vue'
export default {
    components: { 
        AsyncCompo
    }
}
</script>
```

And finally the code of my **actual Async component** called `LoginPopup.vue` that must be rendered after clicking the button:

```html
<!-- LoginPopup.vue -->
<template>
 <div v-if="show1">
    <h2>this is LoginPopup component</h2>
    <p>{{retArticle}}</p>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

export default {


setup() {
    const getArticleInfo = async () => {
        // wait 3 seconds to mimic API call
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    const article = "my article"
    return article
    }
    const show1 = ref(false);
    const retArticle = ref(null);

    onMounted(
        async () => {
            retArticle.value = await getArticleInfo();
            show1.value = true;
        }
    );
    
    return {
            retArticle,
            show1
    }
}
}

</script>
```

When I comment the part below from `AsyncCompo.vue` everything works correctly and my component loads after `3s` when I clicks the button:

```
errorComponent: ErrorCompo,
     timeout: 10
```

But I want to test the `error` situation that [Vue says](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#loading-and-error-states) in my component. I am not sure that my code implementation is absolutely true, but with code above when I use the `errorComponent`, I receive this warning and error in my console:

[image: error image]

I also know that we could handle these situations with `<Suspense>` component, but because my goal is learning `Async Components`, I don't want to use them here. Could anyone please help me that how I can see and test my "error component" in the page? is my code wrong or I must do something intentionally to make an error? I don't know but some articles said that with decreasing `timeout` option I could see error component, but for me it gives that error.